# Linking to the another page, but getting output on the same page (Below) REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

App.js

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <div className="bg-slate-700 w-100 flex flex-col justify-center h-full">
          <h1 className="font-bold text-white text-center justify-center  ">
            User Authentication
          </h1>

          <form className="flex flex-col p-6 m-8 space-y-2 rounded-md bg-white ">
            <div className="text-cyan-500 text-center ">
              Have an account{" "}
              <Link to="/login" className="underline">
                Sign In
              </Link>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </header>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

LoginPage.js

```
import React from 'react'

function LoginPage() {
  return (
    <div>Login 
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage
```

`App.js` is the user register form, under that I have a login button (div).
So onClick "Sign In", I get my Sign In page.
But I'm getting output on the same page, below the `App.js` form.

Comment: you can cast upvote to the solution, this will help us to know if you got fix for your probleml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't getting the same output on the same page, but rather it is that you are ***unconditionally*** rendering the header UI on all pages you are rendering. When you navigate from `"/"` to `"/login"`, the header is rendered regardless.

If you want to ***conditionally*** render the header UI only with certain routes then you should create a layout route component for it. The routes that you want to include the header as part of their UI will be rendered as nested routes, and the routes that you don't want the header with will be rendered outside it.

Example:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const HeaderLayout = () => (
  <>
    <header className="App-header">
      <div className="bg-slate-700 w-100 flex flex-col justify-center h-full">
        <h1 className="font-bold text-white text-center justify-center  ">
          User Authentication
        </h1>

        <form className="flex flex-col p-6 m-8 space-y-2 rounded-md bg-white ">     
          <div className="text-cyan-500 text-center ">
            Have an account{" "}
            <Link to="/login" className="underline">
              Sign In
            </Link>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </header>
    <Outlet />
  </>
);
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<HeaderLayout />}>
          {/* routes that render with header/links/etc */}
        </Route>

        {/* routes that render without header/links/etc */}
        <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Note that with the above configuration you are likely also seeing a warning about a missing route for the root `"/"` path, e.g. some "home page".

Answer (score 1):

It will be displayed below the App.js form because you have defined the header outside the route component. To resolve it, you need to create a separate component with route path="/".

```
function App() {

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route exact path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
        <Route exact path="/login" element={<LoginPage />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

function HomePage(){
return(
<header className="App-header">
        <div className="bg-slate-700 w-100 flex flex-col justify-center h full">
          <h1 className="font-bold text-white text-center justify-center  ">
            User Authentication
          </h1>

          <form className="flex flex-col p-6 m-8 space-y-2 rounded-md bg-white ">

           
            
            <div className="text-cyan-500 text-center ">
              Have an account{" "}
              <Link to="/login" className="underline">
                Sign In
              </Link>
            </div>

          </form>
        </div>
      </header>)
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

App.js is the user register form, under that I have a login button (div).
So onClick "Sign In", I get my Sign In page.
But I'm getting output on the same page, below the App.js form.